# Network Flow Matrix on Hashicorp Consul

Tags: linux, bash, curl, consul, hashicorp

I wanted to know if there's a means to generate network flow matrix with consul, or a command calling the API using curl to retrieve network services, ports associated with a host and generate the matrix.

Thanks.

I've try some curl api calls, I only had few informations but not the entire web of hosts and services related to each one of them.